# Creating a FileManager Maya python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

hey guys i'm trying to make a Filemanager, but i'm really stuck. my first problem is that when my window is open and i write the path in the textfield and then applying ok it's not working. then maya started to throw me this "name 'MNGR_Window' is not defined #" but it worked perfectly before. the project was to create a filemanager where you write the name of the object and then choose the path (project1 and so on). And specify if it's props chara or scene. each of them must have 3 folder(if the user choose chara, i need to create 3 folder like model, texture, shading) then you press the button create and it is supposed to create a path like B\project1\props\table
in table i must have 3 folder texture, model, shading. i'm really stuck
thanks already guys.

```
class MNGR_Window(object):
    
    def make_dir(path):
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        return path
        
    def MakeFolders(*args):
            userInput = cmds.textField('textBox', q=1, tx=1)
            path = make_dir(userInput)
            print('{0} has been created'.format(path))
        
#Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.window = "MNGR_window"
        self.title = "File Manager"
        self.size = (400,400)
        
        #close old window
        if cmds.window(self.window, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window, window = True)
            
          #create new window  
        self.window = cmds.window(self.window, title=self.title, widthHeight=self.size)
        
        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn = True)
        selected = cmds.ls(sl=True,long=True)
        
        cmds.text(self.title)
        cmds.separator(height=20)
        
        cmds.text(label="Name")
        tb=cmds.textField("textBox", tx ="")
     
        cmds.optionMenu(label= "Projet")
        
        prod1=cmds.menuItem(label = "Projet1")
        prod2=cmds.menuItem(label = "Projet2")
        prod3=cmds.menuItem(label = "Projet3")
        prod4=cmds.menuItem(label = "Projet4")
        
      
        cmds.optionMenu(label= "Type")
        
        Props=cmds.menuItem(label = "Props")
        Chara=cmds.menuItem(label = "Chara") 
        Scene=cmds.menuItem(label = "Scene")
        
        cmds.button(label="Create", command=MakeFolders)
        cmds.showWindow()
```

myWindow = MNGR_Window()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some oo basics. Unless you want to create classmethods, the methods of a class should be defined by:

```
def someMethod(self, ....):
    doSomething
```

So you should change your make_dir and MakeFolders methods. Then your call of the methods is not correct, methods are called via

```
self.someMethod(...)
```

So in your case you can call it via

```
cmds.button(label="Create", command=self.MakeFolders)
```

If you fix these problems the code can work.

Comment: first of all thank you very much! true, i'm a newbie i edited the code and everything worked fine,  but i'm still stuck for creating different directory and subdirectory depending of the choice

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: i'm so sorry i didn't see you response. i didn't have any error. everything is good so far except i need to be able to enter a project name, chose between project1 and so on. and then assetype, if its a scene chara or props. i should have 3 subfolder in chara for exemple because there rigg, texture etc

Comment: Ah, so it is more program logic and should be asked in a separate question on SO if you like.